# Undefined functions in header file

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a sudoku solver and want to divide my project into different files.

I want my board.c file to handle the creation and printing of the board while the solver.c file will have the solver functions and such.

I currently have three three files. sudokuSolver.c, board.c, board.h

Have I defined the header files incorrectly or am I missing something else?

sudokuSolver.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "board.h"

int main()
{
    int** board;
    board = createBoard();
    printBoard(board);
    free(board);
    return 0;
}
```

board.h:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H_
#define BOARD_H_

int ** createBoard();
void printBoard(int**);

#endif
```

board.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "board.h"

int** createBoard(){
    int array[9][9] = {
        {3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 8, 0, 3},
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 2},
        {0, 4, 1, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0},
        {7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0},
        {9, 0, 7, 2, 8, 5, 3, 4, 0},
        {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 9, 0},
        {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 7, 5, 6, 0}
    };
    
    int k, **board;
    board = malloc(9*sizeof(int *));
    for(k = 0 ; k < 9 ; k++)
        board[k] = malloc(9*sizeof(int) );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return board;
}

void printBoard(int** board){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

EDIT: When I try to compile the code with `gcc sudokuSolver.c board.h board.c` in the terminal.
After compiling I now have an executable a.exe file that runs the program correctly.

Now I run into a new problem. After the code is compiled I try to run the code directly from Visual Studio Code (Ctrl+Alt+N) But still receive this error:

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbnvRga.o:sudokuSolver.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `createBoard'
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbnvRga.o:sudokuSolver.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `printBoard'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: _How_ do you try to run your code?

Comment: As for your problem, how do you build your program? Please show us the commands used, or how you configured your environment to build.

Comment: It's not "running" the code, it's _compiling_.  The error specifically is the linker step.  Clearly you forgot to compile both c files and then link them.

Comment: Considering that you mention Visual Studio Code, I can only assume that you haven't configured a `tasks.json` file to build with multiple source files. The default of VSCode is to build only the *single* source file in the active tab. Please read e.g. [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) on how to configure VSCode with MinGW, pay close attention to the configuration files (especially `tasks.json`).

Comment: With that said, using the `tasks.json` file to built smaller projects with a few source files is a possibility, for larger projects with multiple source files you should consider other tools to help you build. The most common (which comes with MinGW) is `make` and *makefiles*. But these days it's more common to use *meta-build tools* where you can list the files in a simple format, and then the tools generate the files needed to actually build the application. Two popular alternatives include CMake and Meson.

Comment: If your original quesiton is answered please open a new question for new issues.  Querstions are not intended to be a running commentary and diminishes the value for others seeking answers to specific questions

Answer (score 0):

As Some programmer dude pointed out. I had to configure VSCode to be able to compile multiple source files.

I solved this by adding

```
,
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc *.c -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

in settings of the code Runner extension